# Python: Replace Item in Tuple Converted to List

Tags: python, list, tuples

Recently came into a weird problem. I'm trying to change an item in a tuple I've converted to a list.

But what I had,

```
paths = [(1,2),(2,3),(2,0)]
plist = []

for pathlist in paths:
    for n in range(0, len(pathlist)):
        if pathlist[n] == 2:
            plist = list(pathlist)
            plist[n] = 4
            pathlist = tuple(plist)
            print(pathlist)
print(paths)
```

Didn't actually change the value in the list `paths`, i.e. it stayed the same as originally, even though I could tell from `print(pathlist)` that it had been modified correctly. And I can't remove it and append it because that would offset the for loop. Thanks for your help, guys.

Comment: What are you going for here?  I'm not sure I understand what you expect `paths` to be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the pathlist var is a new instance, it will not affect the paths list members.

try this:

```
for i in range(len(paths)):
    pathlist = paths[i]
    for n in range(0, len(pathlist)):
        if pathlist[n] == 2:
            plist = list(pathlist)
            plist[n] = 4
            paths[i] = tuple(plist)
            print(paths[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only changing the list-copy you modified. You're not directly modifying `paths`.

Do it like this:

```
>>> for i, pl in enumerate(paths):
    for j, n in enumerate(pl):
        if n==2:
            pl = list(pl)
            pl[j] = 4
            paths[i] = pl


>>> paths
[[1, 4], [4, 3], [4, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

you should append the pathlist to some list in each turn...try this one

```
paths = [(1,2),(2,3),(2,0)]
flist = []
for pathlist in paths:
    for n in range(0, len(pathlist)):
        if pathlist[n] == 2:
            plist = list(pathlist)
            plist[n] = 4
            pathlist = tuple(plist)
            flist.append(pathlist)
print(flist)
```

the output will be

```
[(1, 4), (4, 3), (4, 0)]
```

Answer (score 0):

While initially `pathlist` points to an element of `path`, that link is lost when it is reassigned within the loop.

```
for pathlist in paths:
    ...
    pathlist = 'new value'
```

Try this simpler case with a list of integers.  `alist` is not changed.

```
alist = [1,2,3]
for x in alist:
    x = x*2
```

But if the elements are lists, they can be changed without loosing that link to `alist`.

```
alist = [[1],[2],[3]]
for x in alist:
    x[0] = x[0]*2
```

Unfortunately, for these purposes, your tuples are more like integers than lists.  You either have to use indexing to modify `alist[i]`, or rebuild the list as in the list comprehension answer.